# "vite is not recognized ..." on "npm run dev"

Tags: node.js, npm, vite

I'm using Node.js and npm for the first time, I'm trying to get Vite working, following the tutorials and documentation. But every time I run into the problem:

> 'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am unable to find a solution.

I tried restarting pc, reinstalling node.js and several procedures to create vite project but in vain.

**Commands and responses** I run when I try to create a vite project: 
`npm create vite@latest` 
>> my-portfolio >> *vanilla & vanilla* 
`cd my-portfolio` 
`npm install` >>resp: *up to date, audited 1 package in 21s found 0 vulnerabilities*
`npm run dev` 
resp:

```
> my-portfolio@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Does your PATH variable include a vite executable?

Comment: @OneCricketeer how can I check and possibly fix this?

Comment: Open Control Panel and inspect your Environment variables. The error has nothing to do with npm

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't think vite should be in the path.  `npm run dev` should use the version of vite installed with the project.   Using a different version somewhere in the path could cause problems.  If not for this project, then maybe for others.

Answer (score 148):

Try to install the packages to make it work

```
npm install
```

or

```
npm i
```

Comment: But first we need to ensure that Vite is added under devDependencies in package.json file: **"vite": "^4.0.0"**

Answer (score 46):

For this error use the following command on your terminal in the present working directory of the project

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

first, try to install a node package manager and then run npm run dev hope it will work

Answer (score 11):

Install Dependency Using Below Command.

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn install
```

**If you want to add vite manually use below commands**

```
npm i vite
```

or

```
yarn add vite
```

**on project folder run code using below commands.**

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
yarn dev
```

Comment: this works for me, I don't how many people facing this problem, but definitely they can try this code, but we can make more simply, like after create vite project, just do one thing "yarn add vite" and then "yarn dev" that's it.

happy coding

Answer (score 9):

According to documentation https://vitejs.dev/guide/#community-templates

```
npm install
npm run dev
npx vite build
```

Answer (score 6):

Install vite as a dev dependency first

```bash
npm i vite@latest -D

npm run dev
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Even a simple explanation like "Install vite as a dev dependency first" would be better.

Answer (score 5):

For me I had a project I created on one computer and it had this in devDependencies:

```
"vite": "^3.1.0"
```

I did `pnpm install` and it reported everything was fine, but I was getting the error.  I ran `pnpm install vite` and it installed it again with this:

```
"vite": "^3.1.8"
```

After that it worked fine.  So try using npm, yarn, or pnpm to install the vite package again and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

```
yarn add vite
```

on project folder to add vite,
and run

```
npm run dev
```

again.

- remember to update your node version to 18, LTS from 17 might not support this installation.

**update:**

I try to fresh install again my Laravel 9.19, since i had update my node to version 18, `npm install & npm run dev` just work fine without yarn.

Comment: That update information was helpful `npm install & npm run dev`. Thanks @irvine48.

Comment: thank you this is working for me. Am actually creating a frontend in react with the help of vite and then next day my facing this issue thank you for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following works just fine!

```
npx vite build
npm i
npm run dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If `vite` isn't installed, how does the first step work?

Answer (score 2):

I changed NODE_ENV environment variable to `development` ( earlier it was `production` - which should not be the case, as dev-dependencies won't get installed by `npm install` or `yarn` )

Before running `npm install` or `yarn`, make sure `NODE_ENV` environment variable is not set to `production` if you running locally for dev purpose.

Answer (score 2):

try `npm install`

then `npm run build`

Answer (score 1):

Using yarn:

1. `yarn add vite`
2. Then `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Check if vite is installed globally on your system. If not, you can try installing it globally by running `npm install -g vite`. This will make the vite command available throughout your system.

Answer (score 1):

I use Linux Ubuntu, and facing this problem,
so when run `npm install` it install Vite but not global
so i have to run `npm install` then run `sudo npm install -g vite`
then run `npm run dev`
and the problem solved with me.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation.

The problem is vite.cmd is not in the system or user PATH variable, so it cannot be found when it is executed from your project folder.

To fix it, you should temporarily add the folder where vite.cmd is in your PATH variable (either for the entire system or your user). I recommend adding it just for your user, and keep in mind you should probably remove it after you stop working on that project, because this could affect future projects using the same build tools.

To do this:

- My PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Click on Environment Variables (alternatively just use the start button and begin typing Environment, you should get a direct link)
- On "User variables" find "Path" and edit it.
- Add a new entry for the folder where vite.cmd is. Example "C:\dev\reactplayground\firsttest\test01\node_modules.bin" Check your project folder to find the right path.
- Make sure your close and open your console for this change to affect.
- Go back to your project root folder and run "vite build", it should work now.

Comment: Normally vite is not installed globally, it is installed under node_modules in the project directory.   Running with 'npm run dev' should use the version installed with the project.   Having a certain version in your global path might mess with other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need Node version 15 or higher, I had the same problem because I was using an older version of it.

Comment: I've got Node version 16.15.0 and also had the same problem like @MaN8fy. So Node in an older version of  <15 cannot be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and I was finding the error

`create-vite : command not found`

I resolved by running the command:

`npm i create-vite`

From there you can continue with running the command:

`npm create vite@latest`

Reference:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-vite
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Gone through this Error in last Couple of Hours.
My Solution will  be --

1. Go to Package.json First
2. Delete the Package which is making Error while running (if It's Running) .
3. If it's not the Case Make Sure ur in Right( Correct ) Repo in which vite is able to Run.
4. If Both Cases Don't Work then Tre to install the Dependency One by One which are Present and try to Run after it .
5. Surely Changes  will be Reflected in the Terminal .
6. Remove changes or Install dep. Others again (which are left) and u r good to go .
   Note - **Always Keep Look at the Terminal after Single Changes . That's how u debug Code adn Improve It**

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. First `npm install vite`
2. Then `npm run dev`

Comment: `vite` should probably be a dev dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507006/) suggesting `npm i` before `npm run dev`, make sure you don't have a proxy. Sometimes the problem is with your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

with qwik i had this same issue,
fixed by upgrading node
from

```
nvm uninstall v16.0.0
```

to

```
nvm install v16.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked out so well for me.**

First install npm using `**install npm**` command in your terminal.

Then run your Node local server using `**npm run dev**` command.

After that, run your Node server to production by using the following command `**npm run build**`

Finally, run your PHP local server using the `**php artisan serve**`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue none of the other comments worked. it was because i had a slash "/" on a folder name in the path to the directory i was working on